# Loosing the battle - Datediff working but I want to apply a condition

Tags: datediff

I know I'm gonna 'kick myself' when I see the answer but right now I can't see it.

```
SELECT [faxdate]
,DATEDIFF(day, 
 CAST(SUBSTRING(RPT.FaxDate, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RPT.FaxDate, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RPT.FaxDate, 7, 2) AS DATE), getdate()) AS vDiff
```

> faxdate         vDiff 
> 20130704 62 
> 20130705 61
>   
> 20130705 61 
> 20130708 58

Works great, but I want to be able to test the number of days Eg. records over 60 days.
When I add this :

```
WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, 
 CAST(SUBSTRING(RPT.FaxDate, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RPT.FaxDate, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RPT.FaxDate, 7, 2) AS DATE), getdate()) >60)
```

I get: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I have also tried this sql as a derived table and then tested vDiff ....i'm obviously not doing it right

any help would be appreciated

ttfn

Martyn

(Cornwall England and it's not raining .. result !)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT [faxdate],DAY(DATEDIFF(CAST(SUBSTRING(RPT.FaxDate, 1, 4) + '-' +
SUBSTRING(RPT.FaxDate, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RPT.FaxDate, 7, 2) AS DATE), 
getdate())) AS vDiff
```

instead of using where, use having like below

```
HAVING vDiff > 60
```

Comment: datediff requires 3 arguments so this didn't work
(did I mention it's sql server 2008 r2 if it makes any difference)

Comment: @Lupii DATEDIFF requires two arguments only. You chan check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

Comment: @Lupii Did you try CONVERT(SOMESTRING AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) TO make vdiff an integer for the comparision?